# Automatically assign index for every template specialization at compile time via C++ meta programming?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

For example, I want to implement a template function like this:

```
template<typename T>
int GetTypeIndex() {}
```

which always return a determinant zero-based index for the same 'T', and finally a method to get the total count of all 'T's at compile time (a constexpr or macro?)

```
struct A
{
};
struct B
{
};

GetTypeIndex<A>();// returns 0,
GetTypeIndex<B>();// returns 1,

size_t sizeTable[ALL_TYPE_COUNT]; //ALL_TYPE_COUNT equals to 2 hence GetTypeIndex has 2 specialization(A and B)
```

I've already made it by pre-declare every 'T' with some macro wraps the `__COUNTER__`, but it's just not that convenient, and use `__COUNTER__` in other place will corrupt the whole design.

I just want to get rid of those macro tricks.

Edit:
My English is poor so I decide to put on what I made previously with macros to help understanding what I mean.

```
#define INDEXED_TYPE_DEFINE_BEGIN \
template<typename T> int GetTypeIndex() = delete;

#define INDEXED_TYPE_DEFINE_END \
constexpr int INDEXED_TYPE_COUNT = __COUNTER__;

#define AS_INDEXED_TYPE(T) T\
constexpr int Index_##T= __COUNTER__;\
template<> inline int GetTypeIndex<T>() { return Index_##T; }
```

and the user code would be like:

```
INDEXED_TYPE_DEFINE_BEGIN 

typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
}
AS_INDEXED_TYPE(Position)

typedef struct
{
    float min;
    float max;
}
AS_INDEXED_TYPE(Range)

INDEXED_TYPE_DEFINE_END
```

now
`GetTypeIndex<Position>()` would return 0
`GetTypeIndex<Range>()` would return 1
`INDEXED_TYPE_COUNT` equals to 2 and I can use it at compile time
but it's just very inconvenient.

Comment: You do realize that certain limitations of the fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe will prevent the described behavior from working, as described, when there's more than one translation unit getting compiled and linked?

Comment: `std::type_index(typeid(A))`?

Comment: Do you need `GetTypeIndex<T>()` to be a constant expression? Do you need `GetTypeIndex<T>()` to return the same value every time the program is run (or do they just need to be unique and incrementing for every type)? If not, you can solve this with a global counter and each `GetTypeIndex<T>` having it's own static variable

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well that would be the last measure I take if there is no other solution, add some custom pre-build event hooks to preprocess the code and generate some helper code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want a zero-based continuous index with only the types involved by the template specialization of this function, std::type_index seems will generate index for every type no matter if it's involved?

Comment: @Artyer I don't need it's a constant expression, and I realize I can implement it as runtime assignment via a static counter, but the ALL_TYPE_COUNT will be a problem, I want it to be a compile time value

Comment: What is this going to be used for?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm trying to make a ECS framework, use this index to optimize the component accessing to O(1), also pre-allocate an two-dimensions array to host the components at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just keep a single list of all types:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

using all_types = std::tuple<
    A, B, ...
>;  // These don't need to be complete, i.e., just forward declarations work

// Depending on your C++ version, you can use something from https://stackoverflow.com/q/41579477 instead
template<typename T>
inline constexpr std::size_t type_index = []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
    std::size_t result = -1;
    ((std::is_same_v<T, std::tuple_element_t<I, all_types>> ? void(result = I) : void()), ...);
    if (result == -1) throw "type_index<T>: T not in all_types";
    return result;
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<all_types>>{});

template<std::size_t I>
using index_to_type = std::tuple_element_t<I, all_types>;

std::size_t sizeTable[std::tuple_size_v<all_types>];

static_assert(type_index<A> == 0);
static_assert(type_index<B> == 1);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nr6v14Gaz

This doesn't need a macro but forces you to declare all your types in one place (they can't be piecemeal), but it sounds like you are already doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's searching the tuple at compile time to determine the index right? brilliant idea, much better than my macro solution, but can we get rid of that declarations